# CLI S3 download is not available when block public access is on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 which set `block public access` `ON`

I can download file from the aws console.

However when I try to download from the s3 bucket:

```
$ AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=myaccount aws s3 cp s3://mybkexample-bk/ ./ --recursive --no-sign-request

fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

There comes this error.

However, I can list object in AWS console, so this error is because of block public access? If so is it impossible to use AWS CLI with block public access is on?

Comment: `--no-sign-request` explicitly makes a public request, which you've blocked.  Leave this flag off and use a signed request with your credentials to make a non-public request.

Comment: Why are you using `--no-sign-request`?

Comment: I misunderstood, it works without `--no-sign-request`, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html):

> --no-sign-request (boolean)
>
> Do not sign requests. **Credentials will not be loaded** if this argument is provided.

With no credentials being loaded, you're therefore making a *public request* to a bucket which is set to *block public requests*. This results in `AccessDenied`.

Remove `--no-sign-request` so that your request is signed with your AWS credentials and therefore *not public*. This will grant you access if your AWS principal is allowed to copy files from the bucket.